# how to give padding=6 in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the following conv layer, how to add custom padding size to the input tensor?

```
self.conv6 = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
     1024, kernel_size=3, padding=6,dilation_rate=6
 ) # atrous convolution
```

this gives error in tensorflow 2.0 I see the padding='same' option
but what if I want to give padding=6

> File
> "/home/jake/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/utils/conv_utils.py",
> line 202, in normalize_padding
> padding = value.lower() AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 2):

According to the `tf.keras.layers.Conv2D` documentation, `padding` can only be either `'same'` or `'valid'`.

`'same'` ensures that the spatial dimensions are preserved and `'valid'` adds the minimum amount of padding required to ensure that the filter "fits" your spatial dimensions (which can be an issue if `stride` is anything other than one).

You shouldn't need to specify an custom padding size as in most cases it would be unnecessary upsampling. But if you must, you can have a padding layer before the conv layer.

```py
tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D(padding=(6, 6)) # put this before your conv layer
```